# Label Hyperlinks on MS Access 2013 Reports

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink, report

I am having troubles with being able to click hyperlinks on reports in MS Access 2013. My database serves the function of a project log which tracks what projects our group is working on.  The hyperlinks serve as an attachment to a summary file (usually PPT) for each project. Each project is a record in my backend table.

So far I have:

1. Stored the hyperlink as a string in a database table
2. Pull/edit/add hyperlink to a record via Access forms
3. Show the hyperlink and click on it via Access forms
4. Add the hyperlink on a report by referencing a hidden textbox which houses the path

The problem is that the hyperlink shows up on the report correctly and sometimes I am able to click on it, but the majority of the time I cannot click on it.  If I scroll around the report, sometimes I can get the hyperlink active but it seems hit or miss.

Here is the code I used to apply the hyperlink on the report:

```
Private Sub Detail_Paint()

Dim strSource As String

If Report_rptCompleted.txtHL.Value <> "" Then
    strSource = Report_rptCompleted.txtHL.Value
    Report_rptCompleted.lblHL.Caption = Right(strSource, Len(strSource) - InStrRev(strSource, "\"))
    Report_rptCompleted.lblHL.HyperlinkAddress = strSource
    Report_rptCompleted.lblHL.ForeColor = vbBlue
Else
    Report_rptCompleted.lblHL.Caption = "No Attachment"
    Report_rptCompleted.lblHL.HyperlinkAddress = ""
    Report_rptCompleted.lblHL.ForeColor = vbBlack
End If

End Sub
```

Any help on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which view is the report displayed in?

Comment: I'm displaying it in report view.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to go a different route and use a text box instead of a label.

My solution was to drop the label and OnPaint event entirely.  I formatted the textbox to show the file name then referenced the file path in the OnClick event with a FollowHyperlink command.

It is a good bit slower opening the link but works fine.